# PHP's $_SESSION overwritten - only in Firefox (Mozilla)

Tags: php, session, firefox

Within my site, I use the variable **$location** that keeps track of the page the user is viewing. At the end of index.php, the variable is copied into the **$_SESSION** array, so that upon the next request I know where the user was last time (I use it for generating "back" links). So *index.php* goes roughly like this:

> $location = GetLocation(); // gets user location by processing $_POST and $_GET
>   if(!isset($_SESSION['last_location'])) $_SESSION['last_location'] = SomeMeaningfulLocation();
>   .
>   .
>   OutputPage(); // renders the page based on $location
>   .
>   .
>   $_SESSION['last_location'] = $location;

So in OutputPage(), the $_SESSION['last_location'] variable can be used for generating "back" links.
The problem is: **this code works perfectly with MSIE, Chrome and Safari**. It doesn't, however, work with Firefox nor with SeaMonkey (which I like to use for web development). **In these browsers, the "back" links always point to the frontpage**.

Other facts that might be useful:

- Session data is stored in files, server date and time is set right
- I've already tried playing with cache settings (*header('Cache-control: ...')* etc.)  with no difference
- I've tried disabling *network.prefetch-next* in the Firefox/Seamonkey config (no difference)
- The `SomeMeaningfulLocation()` function does NOT return frontpage location  - so to eliminate the possibility the session is 'forgotten' and re-initialized upon each request - which is also excluded by the fact that...
- ... other session variables work just fine (but this one is different in that its content is automatically updated upon each request)
- Nothing wrong can be seen in the apache access/error logs (it is just the same as with the other browsers)
- when i check the $_SESSION['last_location'] value just after the assignment (in the very end of *index.php*), it has the correct value. When i check it in the very beginning of *index.php*, it is already overwritten with the frontpage's location (I repeat: only in Mozilla. In other browsers, these checks show the correct, expected values!)

Thanks in advance, I'm out of ideas :-)

Comment: Have you tried starting FF without any add-ons?

Comment: Do those browsers have cookies enabled? If not, the session cookie won't get svaed on the client and you'll keep using your default. In any case: what's wrong with the browser's native back buttons?

Comment: Do you need to store the previous page in `$_SESSION`? Perhaps you can just use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable instead.

Comment: @Gabi are you using `AJAX` calls?

Comment: Apart from your problem, storing back URLs in sessions is a bad idea: It will horribly break if users open your site in more than 1 tab in their browser.

Comment: @neekab: FF in safe mode = the same behavior.

Comment: @ColinMorelli : Cookies are enabled.

Comment: @Ander2 : No AJAX calls.

Comment: Other comments : It is actually a little more complicated; I do not store a simple URL but an array that describes session "viewing history" and is not used solely for back links. I've simplified the situation for sake of clarity and gave some background sou you know what I'm trying to do. Anyway, if you implement it just the way I wrote in my question (i.e. storing one primitive variable), the issue will take place as well.